# Swap Fn and Cntrl keys on the fly, or per keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, wireless-keyboards

Running PopOs.

I have a Thinkpad laptop. Some of the time I use an external keyboard (Logi MX Mini). The Fn and Cntrl keys are in different places on the two keyboards. I know I can swap the keys in the BIOS, but is there a way to change them on the fly, or more easily when I'm switching between keyboards? I can't go into the BIOS each time to switch it. I use a lot of vim, tmux, and more which makes me heavily dependent on these keys.

Comment: Pop_OS! is not an official Ubuntu flavor, and is therefore off-topic on Ask Ubuntu. You can try asking on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) where it is on-topic.

Comment: No way except re-wiring Keyboard.

Comment: You *might* have luck using xmodmap, if you're using X and not Wayland.